# Css changes in code, doesnt show when debugging mvc 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I use the line

```
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.Amount, new { @class = "editor" })
```

and in site.css I have the code:

```
.editor
{
     width: 100;
}
```

also I use the line
    `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
in the head of the `_Layout`

But when I debug the application, the textbox(Editor) is not 100px wide.
It's as though none of the changes in the css file is showing. I'm using firefox, and also I tried to clear the cache in firefox, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You should supply the unit:

```
.editor { width: 100px; }
```

Comment: I did ofcourse in the css file. But when I look at the css in firebug (firefox). I get an empty rule .editor { }, where did the 100px go? maybe some caching is done?